# Missing font - LaTEx - M1 MacOS

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fonts, latex

I'm fairly new to Python, and I have just purchased a M1 MacBook Air. I'm trying to reproduce some of the codes I've written in my previous windows computer, and they do not seem to be working properly.

When I try to use Matplotlib with LaTEx, I get an error stating that there is a missing font. The funny thing is that the same code runs fine as a regular .py (python) file, but shows an error message when I run it as a .ipynb (Jupyter notebook) file!

```
#Loads libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

print("Finished imports")

#Sets default interpreter to Latex
plt.rcParams.update({
    "text.usetex": True,
    "font.family": "Helvetica"
})

print("Setted Latex interpreter")

%matplotlib inline

A = np.array([1,2,3])
B=A

plt.figure()
plt.plot(A,B)

print("Printed figure")
```

The error message that displays is the following:

```
`Finished imports
Setted Latex interpreter
Printed figure
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
    339                 pass
    340             else:
--> 341                 return printer(obj)
    342             # Finally look for special method names
    343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/IPython/core/pylabtools.py in print_figure(fig, fmt, bbox_inches, base64, **kwargs)
    149         FigureCanvasBase(fig)
    150 
--> 151     fig.canvas.print_figure(bytes_io, **kw)
    152     data = bytes_io.getvalue()
    153     if fmt == 'svg':

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py in print_figure(self, filename, dpi, facecolor, edgecolor, orientation, format, bbox_inches, pad_inches, bbox_extra_artists, backend, **kwargs)
   2293                 )
   2294                 with getattr(renderer, "_draw_disabled", nullcontext)():
-> 2295                     self.figure.draw(renderer)
   2296 
   2297             if bbox_inches:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     71     @wraps(draw)
     72     def draw_wrapper(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs):
---> 73         result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
     74         if renderer._rasterizing:
     75             renderer.stop_rasterizing()

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     48                 renderer.start_filter()
     49 
---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer)
     51         finally:
     52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in draw(self, renderer)
   2835 
   2836             self.patch.draw(renderer)
-> 2837             mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   2838                 renderer, self, artists, self.suppressComposite)
   2839 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     48                 renderer.start_filter()
     49 
---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer)
     51         finally:
     52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in draw(self, renderer)
   3089             renderer.stop_rasterizing()
   3090 
-> 3091         mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
   3092             renderer, self, artists, self.figure.suppressComposite)
   3093 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/image.py in _draw_list_compositing_images(renderer, parent, artists, suppress_composite)
    130     if not_composite or not has_images:
    131         for a in artists:
--> 132             a.draw(renderer)
    133     else:
    134         # Composite any adjacent images together

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/artist.py in draw_wrapper(artist, renderer)
     48                 renderer.start_filter()
     49 
---> 50             return draw(artist, renderer)
     51         finally:
     52             if artist.get_agg_filter() is not None:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in draw(self, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
   1157 
   1158         ticks_to_draw = self._update_ticks()
-> 1159         ticklabelBoxes, ticklabelBoxes2 = self._get_tick_bboxes(ticks_to_draw,
   1160                                                                 renderer)
   1161 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer)
   1083     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1084         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1085         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1086                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1087                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1083     def _get_tick_bboxes(self, ticks, renderer):
   1084         """Return lists of bboxes for ticks' label1's and label2's."""
-> 1085         return ([tick.label1.get_window_extent(renderer)
   1086                  for tick in ticks if tick.label1.get_visible()],
   1087                 [tick.label2.get_window_extent(renderer)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in get_window_extent(self, renderer, dpi)
    908 
    909         with cbook._setattr_cm(self.figure, dpi=dpi):
--> 910             bbox, info, descent = self._get_layout(self._renderer)
    911             x, y = self.get_unitless_position()
    912             x, y = self.get_transform().transform((x, y))

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py in _get_layout(self, renderer)
    307 
    308         # Full vertical extent of font, including ascenders and descenders:
--> 309         _, lp_h, lp_d = renderer.get_text_width_height_descent(
    310             "lp", self._fontproperties,
    311             ismath="TeX" if self.get_usetex() else False)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_agg.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, s, prop, ismath)
    257             texmanager = self.get_texmanager()
    258             fontsize = prop.get_size_in_points()
--> 259             w, h, d = texmanager.get_text_width_height_descent(
    260                 s, fontsize, renderer=self)
    261             return w, h, d

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/texmanager.py in get_text_width_height_descent(self, tex, fontsize, renderer)
    336         dpi_fraction = renderer.points_to_pixels(1.) if renderer else 1
    337         with dviread.Dvi(dvifile, 72 * dpi_fraction) as dvi:
--> 338             page, = dvi
    339         # A total height (including the descent) needs to be returned.
    340         return page.width, page.height + page.descent, page.descent

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py in __iter__(self)
    235             integers.
    236         """
--> 237         while self._read():
    238             yield self._output()
    239 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py in _read(self)
    314         while True:
    315             byte = self.file.read(1)[0]
--> 316             self._dtable[byte](self, byte)
    317             name = self._dtable[byte].__name__
    318             if name == "_push":

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py in wrapper(self, byte)
    164             if state is not None and self.state != state:
    165                 raise ValueError("state precondition failed")
--> 166             return method(self, *[f(self, byte-min) for f in get_args])
    167         if max is None:
    168             table[min] = wrapper

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py in _fnt_def(self, k, c, s, d, a, l)
    465     @_dispatch(min=243, max=246, args=('olen1', 'u4', 'u4', 'u4', 'u1', 'u1'))
    466     def _fnt_def(self, k, c, s, d, a, l):
--> 467         self._fnt_def_real(k, c, s, d, a, l)
    468 
    469     def _fnt_def_real(self, k, c, s, d, a, l):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/matplotlib/dviread.py in _fnt_def_real(self, k, c, s, d, a, l)
    472         tfm = _tfmfile(fontname)
    473         if tfm is None:
--> 474             raise FileNotFoundError("missing font metrics file: %s" % fontname)
    475         if c != 0 and tfm.checksum != 0 and c != tfm.checksum:
    476             raise ValueError('tfm checksum mismatch: %s' % n)

FileNotFoundError: missing font metrics file: phvr7t

<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>
```

I've installed MacTex, so I believe that LaTEx should be installed.
What is interesting is that:

1. The code works fine when I run it from the terminal (using a regular .py file, instead of the Jupyter notebook);
2. The plot is successfully generated if I omit the lines that se the default interpreter to LaTEx.

I've installed python through Anaconda, and I've tried to run the code on Jupyter notebook, Jupyter lab and on VS Code.

Thank you - and sorry in advance if the question is not properly formatted. This is my first question asked here in Stack Overflow.   :-)

Comment: Your code isn't following current methods, and so perhaps you are instead causing problems you may not really have. Your code gives the same error (slightly different than yours) in modern JuptyerLab where Matplotlib works fine whether I run it inside JupyterLab or in a script. (For the script, I had to comment out `%matplotlib inline`.) What in your plot do you need latex in? In Jupyter, you can use latex in the titles and things. For example, in a title you can use `plt.title(r"some fancy label and $a < \gamma$",fontsize=16)` where what is between the dollar signs will be latex.

Comment: <continued> These days if you are employing `rcParams.update()`, there's probably a more supported way now and you should be using that. Occasionally, for real complex things you'll still need to adjust via `rcParams`, but very rarely now. And it should only be a last resort.